# Returning data from Axios API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, axios

I am trying to use a Node.JS application to make and receive API requests. It does a get request to another server using Axios with data it receives from an API call it receives. The second snippet is when the script returns the data from the call in. It will actually take it and write to the console, but it won't send it back in the second API.

```
function axiosTest() {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            // I need this data here ^^
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

...

```
axiosTestResult = axiosTest(); 
response.json({message: "Request received!", data: axiosTestResult});
```

I'm aware this is wrong, I'm just trying to find a way to make it work. The only way I can seem to get data out of it is through console.log, which isn't helpful in my situation.

Comment: I feel like people went a bit to far on this question. Basically, you're missing a return in your axiosTest function, and you didn't wait for the result of it. 

When working with Promises, always return the promise and wait for it when you need the result

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The issue is that the original `axiosTest()` function isn't returning the promise. Here's an extended explanation for clarity:

```js
function axiosTest() {
    // create a promise for the axios request
    const promise = axios.get(url)

    // using .then, create a new promise which extracts the data
    const dataPromise = promise.then((response) => response.data)

    // return it
    return dataPromise
}

// now we can use that data from the outside!
axiosTest()
    .then(data => {
        response.json({ message: 'Request received!', data })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The function can be written more succinctly:

```js
function axiosTest() {
    return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
}
```

Or with async/await:

```js
async function axiosTest() {
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    return response.data
}
```

- [Guide on using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [Info on async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: i cannot seem to get this to work if the function axiosTest() is in a separate file from calling the function: axiosTest().then....   anything special to do in this case?

Comment: same for me, I would like to have the axiosTest() function in a different file then the calling function. Anyone with an idea for this?

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking how to split up your code into separate files. Look into using modules with JavaScript

Comment: What happen if axios come with error ?? how to implement catch block.

Comment: You are the true MVP @kingdaro I've been stuck with my code for ages then I found your answer, what a legend

Comment: This worked for me. Adding a return in front of the axios call.  Makes no sense to me - we have two return statements?  But it works.

Comment: It works for me just using await before axios.post()

Comment: it still returns a Promise, I've been searching for an answer for a couple of days already.

`// now we can use that data from the outside!`
it's still using `.then`, how do you TAKE IT OUT OF .then

Answer (score 23):

I know this post is old. But i have seen several attempts of guys trying to answer using async and await but getting it wrong. This should clear it up for any new references

**UPDATE: May 2023**
This answer is still having lots of interest and have updated/fixed it to use arrow functions

```
const axiosTest = async () => {
  try {
    // use data destructuring to get data from the promise object
    const { data: response } = await axios.get(url); 
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: This is the correct answer -  when you debug the code in your app, the function calling the above will appear to return as well as all other functions in the chain, but then a moment later the code will execute starting after the await.   You will need to make all functions in your app async, and call all of them with await.  Put a breakpoint on the return statement and one on the next line of code in the caller - all will become clear.

Answer (score 15):

you can populate the data you want with a simple callback function,
let's say we have a list named `lst` that we want to populate,
we have a function that pupulates pupulates  list,

```
const lst = [];  
const populateData = (data) => {lst.push(data)}
```

now we can pass the callback function to the function which is making the axios call and we can pupulate the list when we get data from response.

now we make our function that makes the request and pass `populateData` as a callback function.

```
function axiosTest (populateData) {
        axios.get(url)
       .then(function(response){
               populateData(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
               console.log(error);
         });
}
```

Comment: thanks @Fahad_Shovon! this has taken me a day in troubleshooting, which I resolved using your solution

Comment: You hate to see it happen folks.

Answer (score 5):

`axiosTest()` needs to return `axios.get`, which in turn returns a `Promise`.

From there, `then` can be used to execute a function when said `Promise` resolves.

See [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for more info.

Alternatively, `await` can be used from within the scope of some [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function.

```js
// Dummy Url.
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'

// Axios Test.
const axiosTest = axios.get

// Axios Test Data.
axiosTest(url).then(function(axiosTestResult) {
  console.log('response.JSON:', {
    message: 'Request received',
    data: axiosTestResult.data
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

The axios library creates a Promise() object. Promise is a built-in object in JavaScript ES6. When this object is instantiated using the new keyword, it takes a function as an argument. This single function in turn takes two arguments, each of which are also functions — resolve and reject.

Promises execute the client side code and, due to *cool* Javascript asynchronous flow, could eventually resolve one or two things, that resolution (generally considered to be a semantically equivalent to a Promise's success), or that rejection (widely considered to be an erroneous resolution). For instance, we can hold a reference to some Promise object which comprises a function that will *eventually* return a response object (that would be contained in the Promise object). So one way we could use such a promise is wait for the promise to resolve to *some kind of response*.

You might raise we don't want to be waiting seconds or so for our API to return a call! We want our UI to be able to do things *while* waiting for the API response. Failing that we would have a very slow user interface. So how do we handle this problem?

Well a Promise is *asynchronous*. In a standard implementation of engines responsible for executing Javascript code (such as Node, or the common browser) it will resolve in another process while we don't know in advance what the result of the promise will be. A usual strategy is to then *send* our functions (i.e. a React setState function for a class) to the promise, resolved depending on some kind of condition (dependent on our choice of library). This will result in our local Javascript objects being updated based on promise resolution. So instead of getters and setters (in traditional OOP) you can think of functions that you might *send* to your asynchronous methods.

I'll use Fetch in this example so you can try to understand what's going on in the promise and see if you can replicate my ideas within your axios code. Fetch is *basically similar* to axios without the innate JSON conversion, and has a different flow for resolving promises (which you should refer to the axios documentation to learn).

**GetCache.js**

```
const base_endpoint = BaseEndpoint + "cache/";
// Default function is going to take a selection, date, and a callback to execute.
// We're going to call the base endpoint and selection string passed to the original function.
// This will make our endpoint.
export default (selection, date, callback) => {  
  fetch(base_endpoint + selection + "/" + date) 
     // If the response is not within a 500 (according to Fetch docs) our promise object
     // will _eventually_ resolve to a response. 
    .then(res => {
      // Lets check the status of the response to make sure it's good.
      if (res.status >= 400 && res.status < 600) {
        throw new Error("Bad response");
      }
      // Let's also check the headers to make sure that the server "reckons" its serving 
      //up json
      if (!res.headers.get("content-type").includes("application/json")) {
        throw new TypeError("Response not JSON");
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    // Fulfilling these conditions lets return the data. But how do we get it out of the promise? 
    .then(data => {
      // Using the function we passed to our original function silly! Since we've error 
      // handled above, we're ready to pass the response data as a callback.
      callback(data);
    })
    // Fetch's promise will throw an error by default if the webserver returns a 500 
    // response (as notified by the response code in the HTTP header). 
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
};
```

Now we've written our GetCache method, lets see what it looks like to update a React component's state as an example...

**Some React Component.jsx**

```
// Make sure you import GetCache from GetCache.js!

resolveData() {
    const { mySelection, date } = this.state; // We could also use props or pass to the function to acquire our selection and date.
    const setData = data => {
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        loading: false 
        // We could set loading to true and display a wee spinner 
        // while waiting for our response data, 
        // or rely on the local state of data being null.
      });
    };
  GetCache("mySelelection", date, setData);
  }
```

Ultimately, you don't "return" data as such, I mean you can but it's more idiomatic to change your way of thinking... Now we are *sending* data to asynchronous methods.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

IMO extremely important rule of thumb for your client side js code is to keep separated the data handling and ui building logic into different funcs, which is also valid for axios data fetching ... in this way your control flow and error handlings will be much more simple and easier to manage, as it could be seen from this 
[ok fetch](http://ec2-34-243-97-157.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/dev_issue_tracker/view/userstories)

and this 
[NOK fetch](http://ec2-34-243-97-157.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/dev_issue_tracker/view/userstories1)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>

       function getUrlParams (){
          var url_params = new URLSearchParams();
          if( window.location.toString().indexOf("?") != -1) {
             var href_part = window.location.search.split('?')[1]
             href_part.replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g,
                function(m, key, value) {
                   var attr = decodeURIComponent(key)
                   var val = decodeURIComponent(value)
                   url_params.append(attr,val);
             });
          }
          // for(var pair of url_params.entries()) { consolas.log(pair[0]+ '->'+ pair[1]); }
          return url_params ;
       }


      function getServerData (url, urlParams ){
          if ( typeof url_params == "undefined" ) { urlParams = getUrlParams()  }
          return axios.get(url , { params: urlParams } )
          .then(response => {
             return response ;
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
             console.error ( error )
             return error.response;
          })
       }

    // Action !!!
    getServerData(url , url_params)
        .then( response => {
           if ( response.status === 204 ) {
              var warningMsg = response.statusText
              console.warn ( warningMsg )
              return
           } else if ( response.status === 404 || response.status === 400) {
              var errorMsg = response.statusText // + ": "  + response.data.msg // this is my api
              console.error( errorMsg )
              return ;
           } else {
              var data = response.data
              var dataType = (typeof data)
              if ( dataType === 'undefined' ) {
                 var msg = 'unexpected error occurred while fetching data !!!'
                 // pass here to the ui change method the msg aka
                 // showMyMsg ( msg , "error")
              } else {
                 var items = data.dat // obs this is my api aka "dat" attribute - that is whatever happens to be your json key to get the data from
                 // call here the ui building method
                 // BuildList ( items )
              }
              return
           }

        })




    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After 6 hours of fluttering, I realized it was a one-line problem. If you are interfering with the axios life-cycle, you may have forgotten this line:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.requestInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
    this.updateApiCallFor(request.url, true);
    return request;
  });

    this.responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    this.updateApiCallFor(response.config.url, false);

    return response; // THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT !

  }, (error) => {
    this.updateApiCallFor(error.config.url, false);
    throw error;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**async** makes a function *return a Promise*

**await** makes a function *wait for a Promise*

---

*code async/await*

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios
const axios = require('axios')

/* --- */

async function axiosTest() {

    let promiseAxios = axios.get( 'https://example.com' )

    /* --- */

    console.log( await promiseAxios )
        
}

/* --- */

axiosTest()
```

replit.com [Stackoverflow - Returning data from Axios API](https://replit.com/@antelove19/Stackoverflow-Returning-data-from-Axios-API#index.js)

replit.com [Stackoverflow - How to return values from async](https://replit.com/@antelove19/Stackoverflow-How-to-return-values-from-async#index.js)

---

*code async/await* **with return**

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios
const axios = require('axios')

/* --- */

async function axiosTest() {

    console.log( await promiseAxios() )
        
}

/* --- */

axiosTest()

/* --- */

// create function for promise axios and return it
function promiseAxios() {

    return axios.get( 'https://example.com' )
    
}
```

replit.com [Stackoverflow - Returning data from Axios API - return](https://replit.com/@antelove19/Stackoverflow-Returning-data-from-Axios-API-return#index.js)

replit.com [Stackoverflow - How to return values from async - return](https://replit.com/@antelove19/Stackoverflow-How-to-return-values-from-async-return#index.js)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
function axiosTest() {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .catch(error => error);
}

async function getResponse () {
        const response = await axiosTest();
        console.log(response);
}

getResponse()
```

It works, but each function where you want to get the response needs to be an async function or use an additional `.then()` callback.

```
function axiosTest() {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .catch(error => error);
}

async function getResponse () {
        axiosTest().then(response => {
                console.log(response)
        });
}

getResponse()
```

*If anyone knows a way to avoid this please do tell.*

Also checkout **Katsiaryna (Kate) Lupachova**'s [article on Dev.to](https://dev.to/ramonak/javascript-how-to-access-the-return-value-of-a-promise-object-1bck). I think it will help.

Answer (score -2):

```
    async handleResponse(){
      const result = await this.axiosTest();
    }

    async axiosTest () {
    return await axios.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
}
```

You can find check https://flaviocopes.com/axios/#post-requests url and find some relevant information in the GET section of this post.

Answer (score -4):

You can use Async - Await:

```
async function axiosTest() {
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  const data = await response.json();  
}
```

Comment: Howdy! This doesn't answer OP's question. He wants to **return** the data. Also, you are putting the resulting data through a `.json()` call, which is needed when using `fetch` but it doesn't exist (and it's not needed) in `Axios`.

And please remember to provide an explanation and not just a snippet of code. Kindly check "Answer the question" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer