# My XMLHttpRequest isn't receiving data from my local node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm having a problem with receiving the data from my server, and I think the problem is a little less common than I would really want it to be.

I am trying to retreive data of a list of professionals from my company's database, and then format the json data into my html list. I am able to successfully retreive the data from the server, but I can't seem to have my javascript file to detect any changes received (using chrome v.100.0.4896.75 and firefox v.99.0).
*Feel free to ask questions if I am not explaining this correctly.*

I've tried to looking here: [Returning data from Axios API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980380/returning-data-from-axios-api)
But I can't seem to figure out the problem, or even if it's a CORS error that I'm not being told about in the console.

I think the problem is because the request in my node.js server isn't stopping, though I am unsure on how I can check that

[Result of the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS26y.jpg)

- 

My code currently:

The node.js server "server.js"

```
var express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    axios = require('axios');
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();

app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {

    // The config is so that I can add headers, but that part isn't the scope of my problem
    // like with the use of a token to access my database data.
    var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', 
        // I've tested this site and you can easily make GET requests from it, since 
        // this is a similar example, I'm not showing the company's site and token 
        // password for obvious reasons.
    };

    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("GET professionals: ")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        // I want to stop the response and return the data here to index.js
        // Working as intended in my backend server console
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
        // And return error data here in case something went wrong
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server started at port 3000");
});
```

My javascript file "index.js" making a request to the server

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='http://127.0.0.1:3000'; // This will call my server
http.open("GET", url);

http.onreadystatechange=function () {
   if(http.readyState == 4) {
     // I want to retreive my data here, but I'm not getting anything
     // I tested it even if readyState isn't == 4, I'm still not getting anything
     var data=JSON.parse(http.responseText);
     console.log(List of professionals:\n  "+ data);
   }
}
http.send();
```

The head of my markup page "index.html"

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="./node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Edit:
The answer was pretty simple I realize, I thank Danneau for helping with this problem;
All I needed to do was use the res 'response' that's passed and send the response.data from there using res.json(response.data).

Comment: Use the `res` passed into your express handler to send a response: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res. For example, `res.json(response.data)` and `res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal error" })`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068