# value being returned from a promise in pending state

Tags: reactjs, axios, es6-promise

I'm using axios to return API data in a React app. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48980526/3368818) guidance, I created this function:

```
function axiosGet(itemid) {
    const promise = axios(withAuth({
        url: `${apiUrl}/items/?itemid=${itemid}`
    }))
    const dataPromise = promise.then((response) => response.data)
    return dataPromise
}
```

and this code to invoke it:

```
const getData = (theitemid) => {
    const itemdata = axiosGet(theitemid)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.length);  // correctly prints the value I want
            return data.length
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    console.log(itemdata) // at this point, itemdata is: Promise {<pending>}
    return itemdata
}
```

I want `getData` to return the *resolved* value returned from `axiosGet`.

But instead of being resolved, it's in pending status.

Is there some way I can hold off on returning `itemdata` until it is actually resolved?

Answer (score 0):

you have two many options, you can return promise or await the result

```
const getData = async (theitemid) => {
    const itemdata = await axiosGet(theitemid)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.length);  // correctly prints the value I want
            return data.length
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    console.log(itemdata) // at this point, itemdata is: Promise {<pending>}
    return itemdata
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `getData` *is basically the same thing as* `axiosGet`, the fact that you went ahead and created `getData` to me is an indicator that your difficulty is with *using functions that return promises.*

Such functions are also called, *asynchronous functions.*

Do not despair, this is not an easy thing to grasp, especially for self-taught web developers in 2022.

I hope this code might help you wrap your head around what you want to do:

```js
// setup 1: rename axiosGet to getData 
const getData = axiosGet;

// setup 2: define a function with the actions you want to 
//          execute on/with the data once it is available.
function actionOnData (data) {
    // replace this with what you want to do
    console.log(`I like this data: "${data}"`);
}

// option 1: use the "await" keyword
const myData = await getData(myIdentifier);
actionOnData(myData);

// option 2: use the original, callback-based syntax for promises
getData(myIdentifier).then(actionOnData);
```

In both cases, what will happen is that when your data is available, the actions in the `actionOnData` function will be executed.

I am aware that what you might be trying to do in your React application might not be as simple as the scenario I showed above.

For example:

1. You might want something else, for example, another asynchronous operation, to commence before or after doing the stuff you want to do in `actionOnData`.
2. You might want, in doing the stuff you want to do in `actionOnData`, to access and/or interact with other parts of your React application (for example, with component state).

In either case, more knowledge and experience with Promises will make a big difference in how you will be able to find your way around these situations.

My advice would be to use the `async` and `await` keywords because they create the abstraction of "linear execution" and hence they will help you **get the job done** until you are more comfortable with promises and how they work exactly without this added layer of syntactical sugar.

Until then, enjoy using your `async` and `awaits`!

PS: To add error handling to `axiosGet` use the following:

```
function axiosGet(itemid) {
    return axios(withAuth({
        url: `${apiUrl}/items/?itemid=${itemid}`
    }))
        .then(response => response.data)
        .catch(error => { console.error(`axios error: ${error}`) });
}
```

Comment: Should 'async' be used anywhere in the code here?

Comment: Yes, you can only use `await` inside of a function that had been defined with the keyword `async`, this means that you would have to change the definition of the function from within you are using `await` for you to be able to use that keyword. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Unfortunately, I still don't get my data. The result I get from option 2 is: I like this data: "undefined"

Comment: Try to add some error handling into axiosGet as shown in the edited answer.