# How to send a reply in telegram using the response from the nodejs parser

Tags: node.js, axios, telegram, cheerio, telegraf

If you just parse the page and output the answer to the console, then everything works correctly and the desired answer comes.

[image]

if this answer is added to the telegram bot's response using the *await ctx.reply* telegraph, an error occurs.

Unhandled error while processing..

```
node_modules\telegraf\lib\core\network\client.js:293
            throw new error_1.default(data, { method, payload });
```

```
response: {
    ok: false,
    error_code: 400,
    description: 'Bad Request: message text is empty'
  },
  on: {
    method: 'sendMessage',
    payload: { chat_id: 27190544, message_thread_id: undefined }
  }
}

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

how do I add a parser response to a bot? help me please

```
const { Telegraf, Markup } = require('telegraf');
const BOT_TOKEN = "*****************************************";
const bot = new Telegraf(BOT_TOKEN);
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

async function getString() {
    await axios.get("https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h10/current/").then((response) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
      const table = $("table");

      for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        let tr = $(table[i]).find("tr")[4];
        console.log(tr.tostring());
        return $(tr).text();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("Fetch error " + err));
  }
  
bot.start((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('restart!')
});

bot.command('test', async (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("Click it", Markup.inlineKeyboard(
        [
            [Markup.button.callback('PEACE', 'PEACE')]
        ]
    ))
});

bot.action('PEACE', async (ctx) => {
    await ctx.answerCbQuery()
    await ctx.reply(getString())
});


bot.launch();
```

Comment: `return await axios.get(` and `await ctx.reply(await getString())`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from Axios API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980380/returning-data-from-axios-api)