# Setting req.body after Axios.get promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios

I've been stuck on this for a few days and I know that there is an easy answer and its something that I'm overlookng. Console.log is synchronous and I'm able to get the return value from Googles Distance API, but when I try and set req.body["OTHER nRow1"]= I get a cannot ready property toString of undefined (in a pdftk (pdffiller npm)). So, I think I'm still returning the promise. How do I set req.body to the results of the axios get? I've gone down the rabbit hole and I've tried everything. Thank you.

```
        fetchDistance = async function(DISTANCE, req) {
          return axios
            .get(DISTANCE)
            .then(response => {
              console.log();
              const miles = response.data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
                .replace("mi", "")
                .trim();
              return miles;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
            })
            .then(result => {
              console.log("toLoc: " + result);
              req["OTHER nRow1"] = result;
              return result;
            });
        };
        var AirportMiles;
        fetchDistance(DISTANCE, req.body)
          .then(function(result) {
            console.log(DISTANCE + "DISTANCE!!!");
            console.log(result + "RESULT!!!");
            console.log((req.body["OTHER nRow1"] = result));
            return result;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          })
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data + "DATA!!!!!");
            getData(data);
            return (req.body["OTHER nRow1"] = data);
          });
        console.log("REQ: " + req.body["OTHER nRow1"]);
        req.body["Text13"] = perdiem[0].mileage.MileageCost;
      }
      var mi;
      const getData = data => {
        mi = toInt(data);
      };
      req.body["OTHER nRow1"] = mi;
      // Mileage to Form END
```

Comment: If you have the ability to use async functions, it would be much easier to convert all your promise chains to `await`.

Comment: Not sure I understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620694/how-to-return-response-of-axios-in-return I followed this answer but I get no dice.