# Promise is resolved to undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I am sorry if it is simple question, I'm new to javascript

So I have simple axios GET request. It is used three times in my code, so I thought that I could make it an external function, to avoid duplicating code, to making it cleaner and easy readable

The problem is when I call to that function, return value is undefined. And this is because code is working like synchronous. So I thought that I need to make the function return a Promise, and in function call I have to use `async/await` or `then` syntax to get the response in the right time. But after many tries code is still running as synchronous

I read a lot of theory on promises and how they work, got a solid understanding of when they change states, but something goes wrong when I try to implement them on my own

### Here is the function that retrieves data

```
const getMessagesFromChat = async (JWT_header, chatId) => {

    if (JWT_header !== '') {
        //1 let messages
        //4 return
        axios.get(`${SECURED_API_PATH}/messages/chat/${chatId}`, {
            headers: {authorization: JWT_header},
            params: {size: 80, page: 0}
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('messages (fetch)', response.data)
                //1 messages = response.data
                //1 return messages
                return response.data  //2
                //3 return Promise.resolve(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error, error.response)
            })
        //5 return Promise.resolve(messages)
    }
}
```

I marked comments with numbers based on what I've tried

1. make a variable and return it in `then` block
2. make function `async` so everything it returns is wrapped in promise
3. return explicit promise using `Promise.resolve()` in `then` block
4. return the whole request as a promise
5. return explicit promise using `Promise.resolve()` after the request

All responses except 4 were undefined. In 4 variant log statement shows the promise object itself instead of promise value. In other variants log statement shows first `undefined` response and then the actual response from request
I tried to implement second advice from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620694/how-to-return-response-of-axios-in-return/45622080
 but it did not work.

### This is the function I tried to use to get the result (onClick)##

```
const selectChat = () => {
        const JWT_header = getToken()
        if (JWT_header !== null) {
             try {
                 const messages = await getMessagesFromChat(JWT_header, chatId)
                 console.log('messages (after fetch)', messages)
                 //setMessages(messages)
             } catch (error) {
                 console.log(error)
             }
        } else {
            setIsLoggedIn(false)
        }
```

#### or

```
const selectChat = () => {
        const JWT_header = getToken()
        if (JWT_header !== null) {
             getMessagesFromChat(JWT_header, chatId)
             .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                setMessages(response)
              })
             .catch (error =>console.log(error))
        } else {
            setIsLoggedIn(false)
        }
```

But none of them worked as expected


What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getMessagesFromChat` doesn't return anything. You need `return axios.get/* ... */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't `return` anything. A `return` statement in a `then` callback is not sufficient, you'd still have to return the promise chain itself from the outer function.

Use either `.then()` syntax:

```
function getMessagesFromChat(JWT_header, chatId) { // no `async` here
    if (JWT_header !== '') {
        return axios.get(`${SECURED_API_PATH}/messages/chat/${chatId}`, {
//      ^^^^^^
            headers: {authorization: JWT_header},
            params: {size: 80, page: 0}
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('messages (fetch)', response.data)
            return response.data
        })
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(undefined)
//      ^^^^^^ important for chaining
    }
}
```

or `async`/`await` syntax:

```
async function getMessagesFromChat(JWT_header, chatId) {
    if (JWT_header !== '') {
        const respnse = await axios.get(`${SECURED_API_PATH}/messages/chat/${chatId}`, {
//                      ^^^^^
            headers: {authorization: JWT_header},
            params: {size: 80, page: 0}
        });
        console.log('messages (fetch)', response.data)
        return response.data
    }
    // else return undefined
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful, especially the .then syntax example
Guess I need to understand basics of promises before going to async/await